# Update arraylist size as a count in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

---Insertion---

```
  db.mycollection.insert({'foo':[1,2,3,4]})
  db.mycollection.insert({'foo':[5,6,7]})
```

--ArrayList Count---

```
  db.mycollection.aggregate({$project: { count: { $size:"$foo" }}})
```

I want to update my collection with count of arraylist size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that completely on server side using MongoDB as of today. You'll have to use some client side code. In the mongo shell you can do:

```
db.mycollection.find().forEach(function(doc){
  doc.fooSize = doc.foo.length;
  db.mycollection.save(doc)
)
```